# Flash QuickBox2d skinMc.gotoAndPlay(1);

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, skin

I have this quickBox2d code to add a cricle to the stage:

```
var ball:QuickObject = sim.addCircle( {skin:skinMc, x:10, y:10, radius:3, density:0 } );
```

The skinMc contains animations so I want to be able to refer to it like this:  skinMc.gotoAndPlay(5);  but it says

> Type Coercion failed: cannot convert skinMc$ to flash.display.MovieClip.

ball.gotoAndPlay(5); doesn't work either since it's a QuickObject, not an mc...

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: try referencing it as an array Ball[0].gotoAndPlay(5), i couldnt find box2d for flash to have alook at it.

Comment: Hi parele, I tried and it gives me >ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on com.actionsnippet.qbox.objects.CircleObject and there is no default value.

Comment: i was expecting that, if you can paste a link where to find this box2d library i will work it out

Comment: I got it from sourceforge> http://sourceforge.net/projects/box2dflash/files/box2dflash/Box2DFlashAS3_2.0.2/Box2DFlashAS3_2.0.2_.zip/download

and then the quickBox2d plugin: http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/QuickBox2D_1.1.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ball.userData.gotoAndPlay(5);
```

userData will be a DisplayObject populated by QuickBox2D.

Answer (score -1):

```
var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D
var ball:QuickObject = sim.addCircle( {skin:skinMc, x:10, y:10, radius:3, density:0 } );

//something along these lines
```

So to reference the object you can use:

```
sim.gotoAndPlay("5");
```

im not 100% on what your doin but i installed both packages and created a quick document and it works fine on my machine.
if need be try this link http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/08/25/simplify-your-box2d-projects-with-quickbox2d/

if this fails,send me your file or else let me know how you go.

Comment: Doesn't work > (Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 34 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type com.actionsnippet.qbox:QuickBox2D.)

I don't see how it will work. Sim is the simulations. I need to refer to the skin of a specific object within the simulation.